# How to get group owner by CSOM

Tags: c#, csom

I am working with Sharepoint Online and CSOM and I need to get the owner of a 
 specific group.

I tried to load data from ClientContext, and got a exception with the message "unknown error".

Here is the code I tried.

```
MC.ClientContext context = new SPClient.ClientContext("sit url");
MC.Group group = context.Web.SiteGroups.GetById("group id");
context.Load(group, x => x.Owner);
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

What's the correct method to get the information that I needed?

Comment: have u tried debugging to see if u are getting x.Owner.

Comment: I have tried and can't get the value. It hasn't been initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by a quite strange way.
The code is something like this:

```cs
ClientContext context = new SPClient.ClientContext("sit url");
Group group = context.Web.SiteGroups.GetById("group id");
context.Load(group, x => x.Owner.PrincipalType,  x => x.Owner.LoginName);
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
context.Load(group.Owner);
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

I need to call the ExecuteQuery method twice to get the object of owner.
I don't know why. But it works.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. You don't need the second execute but you do need to explicitly specify the Owner properties i.e. x.Owner will not work but x.Owner.LoginName works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GroupCollection.GetByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj165197(v=office.15)) or [GetById](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee536105(v%3Doffice.15)) to retrieve an existing group and then retrieve the groupowner.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("sit url"))
{
    context.Credentials = credentials;

    var groupOwner = context.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("GroupName"); 
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();     
}
```

Comment: The property of owner in group entity has not been initialized.